# Наследование и область видимости

Tags: ооп, javascript

Ниже приведен пример наследования в JavaScript: создаются объекты - родитель `Animal` с переменной `can_walk` и `name`, и потомок `Human` с именем `'man'`. Еще есть "статический" счетчик `'counter'` в `Animal`. Как сделать так, чтобы `'counter'` был `private` (как в Java). Где именно и как `'counter'` нужно декларировать?

```
function Animal(name) {//name - private
    //can_walk - public
    this.can_walk = true;

    //getName() - public
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    }
}
//getCounter() - public static
Animal.prototype.getCounter = function() {return counter;}
//setCounter() - public static
Animal.prototype.setCounter = function() {counter++;}

function Human() {
    //Декларируем, инициализируем свойства родителя для потомка
    Human.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}

//Функция, реализующая наследование через прототипы
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    var F = function (){};
    F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
    Child.prototype = new F();
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
    Child.superclass = Parent.prototype;
}

//Запускаем наследование
extend(Human, Animal);

//Проверяем наследование
var animal = new Animal('animal');
var human = new Human('man');
console.log(animal.can_walk);
console.log(human.getName());
```

Comment: в javascript нет модификаторов доступа посему никак

Comment: Я это понимаю. Но это не совсем так... К примеру в Animal есть свойство name, и функция getName, что равнозначно private в Java, т.к. к этой переменной нет открытого доступа..

Comment: Спорим вы не напишите на Javascript такого кода где я не смог бы получить доступ к вашему "private" полю напрямую?

Comment: Не спорю :)))   Я только начал осваивать язык и еще плохо знаком с ним. Если несложно, приведите, пожалуйста, пример, как Вы можете доступиться к переменной name в Animal.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, чтобы записать counter как static переменную, нужно инициализировать переменную:

```
Animal.counter = 0;
Animal.getCounter = function {return Animal.counter;}
Animal.setCounter = function (param) {Animal.counter = param;}
```

Можно добавить в класс Animal переменную "this.counter = 0" и проверить, что статическая переменная "Animal.counter !== this.counter".

Все хорошо описано в статье: http://karaboz.ru/?p=9

Ответ на вопрос: если статическую переменную и можно сделать private, то для этого нужно использовать сложные шаблоны программирования (паттерны).

Answer (score 0):

```
function Animal(name) {//name - private
    //can_walk - public
    this.can_walk = true;
    var counter; //не будет доступна извне
    //getName() - public
    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот посмотрите здесь http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/inheritance#private-chleny, очень не плохо написано.

Comment: То есть, если вы хотите сделать приватные методы, вам нужно пересмотреть объявления функций в прототипе.И выбрать наследование методом фабрик.

Comment: @almac, Вы путаетесь с понятие static)<br>
static - это метод класса, а не его экземпляров<br>

P.S:

Обычный метод экземпляра:

    Animal.prototype.getCounter = function() {return counter;}

Метод класса( static ):

    Animal.getCounter = function() {return counter;}

Общее свойство экземпляров:

    Animal.prototype.shared_var = {}

Comment: Как я понимаю,если Animal.prototype.getCounter не копируется никуда, и эта функция содержится только в единственном числе (на нее нет копий), то это static метод. А Animal.getCounter будет наследоваться и в каждом потомке будет копия этого метода, так что это уже не static (нужно смотреть в рамках примера). А вот Animal.prototype.shared_var - это static свойство, но в тоже время public (т.е. открытое свойство). Мне надо такое же, но private static. Я перешел с программирования Java на Javascript, и вижу, что слишком много путаницы в JS среди программистов...

Comment: В JS статик - это не то что не копируется, а то, что не использует ( this ) и локальных переменных конструктора

Comment: Ясно, спасибо :)   Но вообще, возможно ли закрыть доступ к свойству shared_var в Вашем последнем примере и оставить его доступным любому потомку этого объекта через функцию getSharedVar?

Answer (score 0):

Для закрытия доступа к переменной можно использовать замыкание

```
var Animal = function(){
    var counter
    function Animal(name) {//name - private
        //can_walk - public
        this.can_walk = true;

        //getName() - public
        this.getName = function() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    //getCounter() - public static
    Animal.getCounter = function() {return counter;}
    //setCounter() - public static
    Animal.setCounter = function() {counter++;}

}();
```